# Replacing every letter in a string with the letter following it in the alphabet

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, caesar-cipher

I am working through some of the exercises at Coberbyte. The instructions for this exercise are to replace every letter in a string with the letter following it in the alphabet (i.e., c becomes d, z becomes a), then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally return this modified string.

1. Is there a better way to advance characters alphabetically than converting to ASCII, adding one, and converting back?
2. Is there a way to do this with one loop?
3. In general, are there ways to shorten/improve the code?

```
var txt = prompt("Please enter some text: ");
var newTxt = "";
var newTxt2= "";

for (var i = 0; i<txt.length; i++){
  if (txt.charAt(i).contains(" ")){
    newTxt = newTxt.concat(" ");//checks for spaces
  }else if (txt.charAt(i) === "z"){
    newTxt = newTxt.concat("a");//checks for "z" and sets to "a"
  }else{
    newTxt = newTxt.concat(String.fromCharCode(txt.charAt(i).charCodeAt(0)+1));
  }//converts letter to the next letter in the alphabet
}

// checks for vowels and sets to upper case
for (var i=0; i < newTxt.length; i++){ 
  switch(newTxt.charAt(i)){
    case "a":
    case "e":
    case "i":
    case "o":
    case "u":
    newTxt2 = newTxt2 + (newTxt.charAt(i).toUpperCase());    break;
    default:
    newTxt2 = newTxt2 + newTxt.charAt(i);
    break; 
 }
}

console.log(newTxt2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'll note that `str.charAt(n).charCodeAt(0)` is better written as `str.charCodeAt(n)`.

Strings are immutable, so it's better to work on array elements than to build them by character-by-character concatenation.

```
function transform(text) {
    var s = text.split('');
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        // Caesar cipher
        switch(s[i]) {
          case ' ':
            break;
          case 'z':
            s[i] = 'a';
            break;
          case 'Z':     // One case you forgot to handle
            s[i] = 'A';
            break;
          default:
            s[i] = String.fromCharCode(1 + s[i].charCodeAt(0));
        }

        // Upper-case vowels
        switch(s[i]) {
          case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
            s[i] = s[i].toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    return s.join('');
}
```

**Edit note:** My original answer had the for-loop written as `for (var i in s) { ... }`.  As pointed out by @EliasVanOotegem, that is more suited for iterating over object properties than array elements.  As suggested by @plalx and [confirmed with jsperf](http://jsperf.com/transform-letters/2), changing it to `for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) { ... }` makes it *much* faster.  I have therefore amended my response, changing `for (var i in s)` to `for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)`.

---

Note that your solution and the solution above blindly increments every character except spaces.  If you want to increment just letters, then a replace operation would be more appropriate:

```
function transform(text) {
    var caesar = text.replace(/[a-z]/gi, function(c) {
        switch (c) {
          case 'z': return 'a';
          case 'Z': return 'A';
          default:  return String.fromCharCode(1 + c.charCodeAt(0));
        }
    });
    return caesar.replace(/[aeiou]+/g, function(vowel) {
        return vowel.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

You could cheat on the Caesar cipher, mapping both `z` and `Z` to an uppercase `A`, since you know that vowels will need to be uppercased.

---

## Addendum: Follow-Up Q&A

@Nathan asks in the comments…

> 1) I keep reading that strings are immutable and I guess this means that in my code, I'm not really concatenating, I'm replacing. I take it this is bad but I'm not sure why. I understand how your array works, just not why it is better.

If `a` and `b` are strings, when you do `var c = a + b`, then it creates a new string for the result (allocates memory for the length of `a` and `b`, then copies the contents of `a`, followed by the contents of `b`).  If you iteratively do a concatenation for each character in a string, that works out to be O(*n*^2), where *n* is the length of the input.

In contrast, operating on an array of characters lets you modify the elements in place.

> 2) Both your solutions were functions. Is this so that they can be reused? The code is more self-contained and complete?

Even if you call the code just once, putting it in a function is beneficial, because it…
- lets you give your code a name.  Naming is important because it describes the purpose of the code.  Good naming is a form of self-documentation.  Awkward naming is a sign of muddled thinking.
- compartmentalizes the code into small, understandable chunks.  In JavaScript, variables can be scoped by function; without functions, all variables would be in the global scope, and assigning to a global variable can have side effects *anywhere* in your code.

Admittedly, `transform(text)` is not a very descriptive name, the way `caesarCipher(text)` is.  However, the problem was a bit weird and artificial to begin with.  Anyway, it's worthwhile to make it a function, to separate it from the prompting and outputting code.  (Someday you might choose to use the same text transformation, but taking the text from an HTML `<input>` field and outputting the result to a `<span>`.

> 3) How does the function get it's argument (c)?

That's how the [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) function behaves.  If you pass a function as the second argument to `replace()`, then for every match, that function will be called with the matched substring as its first parameter.

Comment: `for...in` is not _a more modern way to write a loop_, it's a way to iterate an object. For arrays, it's recommended you use a _classical_ `for` loop. Besides, there's no reason to write 2 `switch` statements, they can easily be combined

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thanks for the for-loop correction. Indeed, the classical for-loop is much faster, so I have amended my response. However, combining the two switch-blocks would drastically hurt the code clarity.

Comment: Yah, it probably won't make the code more readable... I'm a bit too fond of `switch-case` fallthrough abuse :)

Comment: Thank you. Everyone's answers were excellent. I'm blown away. Three questions for you. 1) I keep reading that strings are immutable and I guess this means that in my code, I'm not really concatenating, I'm replacing. I take it this is bad but I'm not sure why. I understand how your array works, just not why it is better. 2) Both your solutions were functions. Is this so that they can be reused? The code is more self-contained and complete? 3) How does the  function get it's argument (c)?

Comment: @200_success, Actually you should really be caching the `length` property because property lookups are expensive in JS. `for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++)`, also looping backward is slightly faster because you can remove one condition check, `var i = arr.length;` then `for (; i--;) {}` but that might be overkill ;)

Comment: @200_success I was really expecting a regex replacement to be faster since `replace` is a native method and is probably implemented in C++, however my assumptions were wrong.

Comment: @Nathan I've added a follow-up Q&A to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this perhaps? I've used an object as a map for quick vowels lookups and took advantage of the fact that the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function takes a replacement function. The whole transform is done in a **single replace operation**.

*Note: I assume that we were only replacing lowercase letters, but it would be easy to handle all cases.*

```
var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].reduce(function (res, l) {
    res[l] = true;
    return res;
}, {});

'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.replace(/[a-z]/g, function (l) {
    if (l === 'z') return 'A';
    l = String.fromCharCode(l.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
    return vowels[l]? l.toUpperCase() : l;
}); //bcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyzA
```

**EDIT:**

Here's another way to create the map without using reduce. Like pointe out by @JanDvorak, the reduce construct might affect readability, however I like it since it allows you to define the map in a single statement, which is quite useful when you advocate using a single `var` statement.

```
var vowels = {};

['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].forEach(function (l) {
    vowels[l] = true;
});
```

**EDIT2:**

Here's my implementation packaged within a reusable function. I know this is an exercise and that it's probably not meant to be reused, however it's worth knowing how to do it ;)

```
var transformLetters = (function () {
    var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].reduce(function (res, l) {
            res[l] = true;
            return res;
        }, {}),
        rx = /[a-z]/g,
        replaceFn = function (l) {
            if (l === 'z') return 'A';
            l = String.fromCharCode(l.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
            return vowels[l]? l.toUpperCase() : l;
        };

    return function (s) {
        return s.replace(rx, replaceFn);
    };
})();
```

**EDIT 3:** Actually I've created a performance test that compares different solutions and it seems that using a map isin't the fastest way and it's actually slower than performing a double replace. I must say I am quite surprised. Anyway, here's the fastest implementation I could write:

[**PERFORMANCE TESTS**](http://jsperf.com/transform-letters) (includes @200_success solutions)

```
var transform_switch = (function() {
  var rx = /[a-z]/g,
    replaceFn = function(l) {
      if (l === 'z') return 'A';
      l = String.fromCharCode(l.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
      switch (l) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
          return l.toUpperCase();
        default:
          return l;
      }
    };

  return function(s) {
    return s.replace(rx, replaceFn);
  };
})();
```

Comment: uhh... `reduce` is a weird way to convert an array to a bit map. A literal loop would probably be better here.

Comment: @JanDvorak, I hear your, however I really like to take avantage of the `initialValue` parameter and create a map in a single top-level statement. I do not see any disadvantages in using this looping construct.

Comment: what about readability? I found it hard to understand at first reading.

Comment: @JanDvorak Well, perhaps it depends on your comprehension level, but `reduce` iterates over every elements in an array, just like `forEach` would. Then the rest of the code is very similar in both cases, the only difference being that you would have to declare the object in another statement `var` statement instead of passing it as the `initialValue`. Honestly I do not find that this affects readability, but that's my point of view an I might be wrong. Anyway I think that the overall solution is quite comprehensive an efficient.

Comment: as for the second half, what are 97 and 122? I don't like unexplained magic constants.

Comment: @JanDvorak You are right, I've edited the answer to make it a little less magic ;) Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You don't need to use your complicated `vowels` setup with `forEach` or `reduce`. This should be enough: https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/6958147

Comment: @IQAndreas If you want to be extremely inefficient, yes you can. It will take O(n) time to check if the letter is a vowel with your implementation while it takes O(1) time with a map.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the multiple versions you provided. There is a lot going on here. It is going to me awhile to work through these. I will comment more shortly. This is a great way to learn.

Comment: It would be so cool if JS had multiple value returns to allow converting an array into a map with `return key, value`.

Comment: @DavidHarkness as  in `return {"key":"value"} ?

Comment: @mplungjan You can fake it by returning an array: `return [key, value];` Language support would allow `Object.prototype.map`.

Answer (score 2):

1. No, not really. There are other ways, but nothing that is simpler or faster.
2. Yes, you can handle the `z`, the space and the vowels as one case, and the other characters by adding the character code:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i<txt.length; i++){
       var c = txt.charAt(i);
       var index = " zdhnt".indexOf(c);
       if (index != -1) {
           newTxt += " AEIOU".charAt(index);
       } else {
           newTxt += String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
       }
   }
   ```
3. See 2. Alternatively, you could use a regular expression to make the vowels uppercase:

   ```
   newTxt2 = newTxt.replace(/[aeiou]+/g, function(m){ return m.toUpperCase(); });
   ```

(Note that the code in 2 and 3 are exclusive, if you use the code in 2, the code in 3 is not needed.)

Comment: Thank you. Your feedback is excellent. I'm surprised that there is not a better way to advance characters alphabetically, but then again, maybe this is not a very common practice in the real world. I'm going to review this again in the morning. I'm not clear yet on " zdhnt" and " AEIOU", although the latter must be replacing lower case vowels with upper case. So much to learn. This is very helpful.

Comment: @Nathan: The " zdhnt" and " AEIOU" replacement doesn't only turn vowels to upper case, it also keeps spaces unchanged, and wraps from z to a.

Comment: Okay, I'm stuck in a couple places.

Comment: Nevermind, the penny just dropped. Very nice! Wow, my code is so verbose compared to this.